# While dataReader.Read() not executing

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, while-loop

The code executes everything but the While dataReader.Read() loop and I have no idea why. No errors are coming up, it just doesn't actually read the data with the data reader. Many thanks for any help received.

```
Private Sub BtnFind_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnFind.Click
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection
    Dim text As String = txtTeacherID.Text
    Dim dataReader As OleDbDataReader

    Try
        'selects the information from the row where the column has the teacher ID
        myConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\My Documents\database.accdb")
        myConnection.Open()

        cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [TMessages] WHERE TeacherID = '" & text & "'", myConnection)

        dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While dataReader.Read()
            lstItems.Items.Add(dataReader(0))
            lstItems.Items.Add(dataReader(0))
            lstItems.Items.Add(dataReader(0))
            MsgBox("reading")
        End While
    Catch
        MsgBox("Error occured")
    End Try
    dataReader.Close()
    myConnection.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Please use only the relevant tags. Here vba and access-vba are meaningless

Comment: [DataReader.Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx) returns false if there's no data to read. Are you sure the query has successfully returned any rows?

Comment: The only reason to not execute the while loop is if you have no match for your text variable in the database. By the way are you sure that TeacherID is a field of type text in your database?

Comment: @Steve TeacherID is a short text type in the database

Comment: @JeffBridgman All the access rows have data in them. Could it be that the cmd command is wrong and not taking the right data out? Sorry I am new to using databases with vb so I am rather useless!

Comment: A possibility could be some whitespaces present in your variable. Use Trim() to remove any whitespace from the text variable

Comment: @FunkyFrog you are adding the same value three times to the List `lstItems.Items.Add(dataReader(0))`, and as others have pointed out, the value may be blank. Try reading all the fields from the reader `For i = 0 To dataReader.FieldCount` and check the received values.

Comment: @AugustoQ I did this and it worked! Many thanks!!

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting issues.  TeacherID is a number?  Then you would have to get rid of those single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in my comment, you are only reading the same value 3 times

```
lstItems.Items.Add(dataReader(0))
```

And the read value may be in blank, try to use your reader to read all the values recieved in the dataReader thought a loop and check all the values.

```
for i = 0 to dataReader.FieldCount
```